# reading text file against specific words

Tags: java, twitter, text-files, stanford-nlp, pos-tagger

I am creating a tool in Java Eclipse which would distinguish whether a sentence contains a particular word or not.

I am using the twitter4j tool to be able to search for tweets in twitter.

I have used a the stanford NLP tagger to be able to tag the tweets from twitter. This is then stored in a text file.

Here is the code

```
public class TextTag {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException,
 ClassNotFoundException {

 String tagged;

 // Initialize the tagger
 MaxentTagger tagger = new MaxentTagger("taggers/english-left3words-distsim.tagger");

 // The sample string
 String sample = "Output Tagged";

 //The tagged string
 tagged = tagger.tagString(sample);

 //output the tagged sample string onto your console
 //System.out.println(tagged);

 /*pick up some sentences from the file ouput.txt and store the output of
 tagged sentences in another file EntityTagged.txt. */

 FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("Output.txt");
 DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
 BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

 //we will now pick up sentences line by line from the file ouput.txt and store it in the string sample
 while((sample = br.readLine())!=null)
 {
 //tag the string
 tagged = tagger.tagString(sample);
 FileWriter q = new FileWriter("EntityTagged.txt",true);
 BufferedWriter out =new BufferedWriter(q);
 //write it to the file EntityTagged.txt
 out.write(tagged);
 out.newLine();
 out.close();

 }
```

My next step is to use the tagged tweets from EntityTagged.txt and compare these with a string of positive words and negative words.

I have created 2 text files, a list of positive words and a list of negative words, and my goal is to loop through the 10 different tagged tweets in the 'EntityTagged.txt" file against the positive.txt and negative.txt files to find out if a word comes up so i can distinguish if the tweets are positive or negative

My end result should have

Tweet 1: positive
Tweet 2: negative
Tweet 3: negative

etc

At the moment, I am struggling to create an algorithm which can implement this

Any help will be much appreciated

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here's my five-minute algorithm. Store your positive and negative words as delimited strings. Then loop through the words in your tweet to see if they exist in the delimited strings. You'll have to expand the split regex to include all special characters:

```
String positiveWords = "|nice|happy|great|";
positiveWords = positiveWords.toLowerCase();

String negativeWords = "|bad|awful|mean|yuck|sad|";
negativeWords = negativeWords.toLowerCase();

String tweetOne = "nice day happy not sad at all";
tweetOne = tweetOne.toLowerCase();

String[] arrWords = tweetOne.split("\\s");
int value = 0;
for (int i=0; i < arrWords.length; i++) {

    if (positiveWords.indexOf("|"+arrWords[i]+"|") != -1) {
        System.out.println("POS word(+1): " + arrWords[i]);
        value++;
    }
    if (negativeWords.indexOf("|"+arrWords[i]+"|") != -1) {
        System.out.println("NEG word(-1): " + arrWords[i]);
        value--;
    }            
}

System.out.println("positive/negative value: " + value);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. How would I read in text files that I have already created for the positive words, negative words and tweets

Comment: I have an example on GitHub: https://github.com/CoachEd/JavaExamples/tree/master/ReadTextFileExample. This reads a text file line-by-line. Then you can parse each line accordingly.